# Undefined offset: 0 (View: /App/resources/views/index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, local-storage

vengo a publicar esto nuevamente ya que no se resolvió, he estado queriendo trabajar con imagenes y livewire he aplicado las recomendaciones que dan en los dos sitios (livewire y laravel) pero al haber aplicado el siguiente codigo me aparece el error de Undefined offset: 0 (View: /App/resources/views/index.blade.php) el detalle es que al quitar la línea que puse cuando me dio el error no se soluciona, ya no puedo entrar despues del login porque me sigue dando error.

línea de codigo:

```
Storage::disk('publico2')->put($this->nom_imagen,$this->imagen),
```

ya limpié caché del navegador (incluso de los otros navegadores que tengo, aunque no los hubiera usado)

también usé estos comandos pero ninguno me funcionó.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Agrego la parte del formulario donde esta la imagen:

```
<label for="">Imagen</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" wire:model="imagen">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="">Subir Imagen</label>
    </div>
    @error('imagen') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
  </div>
```

Funcion Store:

```
public function store()
    {
      $this->validate([
        'cantidad' => 'required',
        'fecha' => 'required',
        'referencia' => 'required',
        'id_concepto_pago' => 'required',
        'imagen' => 'max:2048'
      ]);


      $aporte = Aporte::create([
        $this->nom_imagen = date('YmdHis').'.jpg',
        $this->imagen->storeAs('imagenes',$this->nom_imagen,'publico'),
        'id_concepto_pago' => $this->id_concepto_pago,
        'cantidad' => $this->cantidad,
        'fecha' => $this->fecha,
        'referencia' => $this->referencia,
        'id_personal' => $this->id_personal
      ]);

      $this->mount();
    }
```

---

coloco lo demás:

index:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  @livewire('aporte-component')
</div>
@endsection
```

mi aporte-component:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #FFBF00">
        @include("livewire.$view")
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @include('livewire.Aportes.table')
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

mi @include('livewire.Aportes.table'):

```
<h1 class="text-center">Aportes Realizados <label for="" class="px-3" style="background-color: #00FF80; font: #aaa;">{{$usuario[0]->nombre}}</label> </h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th><h5>Concepto</h5></th>
      <th><h5>Cantidad</h5></th>
      <th><h5>Fecha</h5></th>
      <th><h5>Estado</h5></th>
      <th colspan="3"><h5>Acciones</h5></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($aporte as $ap)
      <tr class="text-center">
        <td>{{$ap->descripcion}}</td>
        <td>Q{{$ap->cantidad}}</td>
        <td>{{date('d/m/Y', strtotime($ap->fecha))}}</td>
        @if ($ap->activo == 0 || empty($ap->activo))
          <td class="table-danger">Pendiente</td>
        @else
          <td class="table-success">Aprobado</td>
        @endif
        <td>
            <button wire:click="ver({{$ap->id}})" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mx-2">Ver
            <button wire:click="edit({{$ap->id}})" class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-2">Editar
              @if ($ap->activo == 0 || empty($ap->activo))

              @else
                <button wire:click="imprimir({{$ap->id}})" class="btn btn-outline-success mx-2">Imp. Recibo
              @endif

              @can('eliminar_aportes')
                <button wire:click="destroy({{$ap->id}})" class="btn btn-outline-danger mx-2">Eliminar
              @endcan
              @can('aprobar_aportes')
                @if ($ap->activo == 0 || empty($ap->activo))
                  <button wire:click="aprobar({{$ap->id}})" class="btn btn-outline-success">Aprobar
                @else
                  <button wire:click="aprobar({{$ap->id}})" class="btn btn-outline-info">Desaprobar
                @endif

              @endcan
        </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </thead>
</table>
{{$aporte->links()}}
```

mi @include("livewire.$view"):

```
public $view = 'Aportes.create';
```

el create:

```
<h2 class="text-center">Registrar Pago</h2>
    @include('livewire.Aportes.form')
<div class="text-center">
    <button wire:click="store" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
    <a href="{{url('/home')}}" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Refrescar</a>
</div>
```

el form:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="store">
  <label for="">Aporte</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" readonly="" value="{{$concepto[0]->descripcion}}" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Cantidad</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="cantidad" placeholder="Ingrese una Cantidad">
    @error('cantidad') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Fecha</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" wire:model="fecha">
    @error('fecha') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Referencia</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" wire:model="referencia" placeholder="Colocar 0 si fue pago personal">
    @error('referencia') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
  </div>
  <label for="">Imagen</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" wire:model="imagen">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="">Subir Imagen</label>
    </div>
    @error('imagen') <span id="error">{{$message}}</span> @enderror
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

variable $concepto:

```
$concepto = Concepto::whereNotExists(function($query)
            {
                $per = Auth::id();
                $query->select(DB::raw('ap.id_concepto_pago'))
                      ->join('personal as p','p.id','=','ap.id_personal')
                      ->from('aportes as ap')
                      ->whereRaw('concepto_pago.id = ap.id_concepto_pago')
                      ->where('id_usuario','=',$per);
            })->offset(0)->limit(1)
            ->get();
```

espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Cuál es el proceso total que genera el error? Podrías explicar el flujo completo de tu proceso?, Algo así: "Primero voy a mi formulario de registro, luego selecciono un archivo, le doy a guardar y me da error"

Comment: @L.Flor, te explico, antes del error el flujo era, loguearme, tengo una ventana dividida que a la izquierda esta el formulario de registro (creacion) al subir una imagen y darle guardar (me tendría que guardar el archivo) y aparecía StorAs null, luego que le coloqué la línea que mencioné me empezó a aparecer este error después de la pantalla de login. espero haber aclarado la duda.

Comment: El error lo obtienes cuando no subes un archivo o así subas un archivo igual obtienes error?

Comment: Si subo el archivo, pero me aparecía no lo reconocía, cuando me aparecía StorAs null le daba ESC y luego le daba guardar otra vez y guardaba sin problema. PD. tengo en el formulario "enctype= multipart/form-data" por si acaso aunque aparentemente no es necesario, lo que no hice fue hacer una validación de si trae imagen. PD2. uso livewire y no hay requests en los formularios.

Comment: Estás trabajando con vista previa de la imagen? Es mejor que pongas tu elemento <input> file en tu pregunta y adjuntes el código completo de tu controlador para registro

Comment: podrias hacer un dd($request->all()) a tu controlador, parece que hay algun dato que no llega.

Comment: @FelipeUrcia no estoy usando controlador en este caso, sino un componente. no hay requests como mencione antes.

Comment: @L.Flor ya adjunte lo que me pediste, no estoy manejando vista previa dela imagen.

Comment: Cuáles son los atributos de tu modelo Aporte.php?

Comment: te refieres a esto: public $aporte_id, $id_personal, $id_concepto_pago, $activo;
    public $cantidad, $fecha, $referencia, $imagen, $nom_imagen, $per;

Comment: No, imagino que debes tener un folder con tus ,`Models/Aporte.php`, veo que al usar `create()` colocas 7 atributos pero sólo veo el nombre de 5 de ellos, cuál es el nombre de los otros 2 atributos?

Comment: Así es, tengo Modelos/aporte, los otros atributos que miras es uno que dice ID personal ese lo capturo anteriormente por eso no lo válido y el otro es el nom_imagen solo lo uso para el nombre y con ese lo guardo en la BD

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que guardas un nuevo registro no parece ser correcta. Debes tener una forma limpia, además siempre es aconsejable verificar primero que exista un archivo para luego proceder a guardarlo:

```
$nombreImagen = date('YmdHis').'.jpg';
$ruta = null;

if($this->imagen){
    $ruta = $this->imagen->storeAs('imagenes', $nombreImagen ,'publico');
}

$aporte = Aporte::create([
    'nom_imagen' => $nombreImagen,
    'ruta_imagen' => $ruta,
    'id_concepto_pago' => $this->id_concepto_pago,
    'cantidad' => $this->cantidad,
    'fecha' => $this->fecha,
    'referencia' => $this->referencia,
    'id_personal' => $this->id_personal
  ]);
```

Comment: A mi me ha funcionado aunque digas que es incorrecta, la cuestion que no puedo probar tu método ya que desde que paso del login me tira el error, siento que es algo que se cargara en caché o en el storage del explorador.

Comment: Si es desde el login, entonces coloca tu método login y vista index.blade.php porque no tengo visión de eso, creí que el problema radicaba en el método registrar().

Comment: Ya agregué todo, espero no este muy enredado.

Comment: Bien, tienes dos líneas que hacen acceso a un array de índice [0], los cuales son `concepto` y `usuario`, alguno de los dos no tiene data, revisa el error en el navegador y debe mostrarte la línea exacta en la que ocurre el error, para saber cuál de los dos es

Comment: Sería raro, el usuario captura el usuario legeado con un Auth::id() y el concepto es cargado un un metodo mount() el cual a traves de un query captura el primer valor que necesito.

Comment: Entonces el problema puede estar en `concepto`, podrías mostrar cómo haces el query? Ya has verficado que siempre tenga data?

Comment: ya lo agregue, te explico, el query lo que haces que tiene una tabla de conceptos de pago (asi la llamo yo) la cual viene y verifica el personal logueado y mira cual es el siguiente concepto que le toca pagar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115600/discussion-between-l-flor-and-mau-espana).

Answer (score 0):

La solución radicó en el hecho que estaba queriendo obtener una variable mediante un query que no traía datos.

```
$concepto = Concepto::whereNotExists(function($query)
            {
                $per = Auth::id();
                $query->select(DB::raw('ap.id_concepto_pago'))
                      ->join('personal as p','p.id','=','ap.id_personal')
                      ->from('aportes as ap')
                      ->whereRaw('concepto_pago.id = ap.id_concepto_pago')
                      ->where('id_usuario','=',$per);
            })->offset(0)->limit(1)
            ->get();
```

este query en la funcion mount() cargaba un valor previo, pero al no encontrar valor que halar mostraba el problema. para poder solucionarlo me fui a la base de datos y borré un par de registros, no había problema ya que son datos de prueba.